# assembly program, if a>b, square the value of b

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to create a program in Assembly Language, if A>B, double/square the value of B.

I was able to input single digit numbers, like 5 and 3, the answer is supposed to be 9, because it's says in the condition that when the first number is greater than the second number, double/square the second number.

Unfortunately the answer is wrong, it produces " P2" as the answer.

```
pc macro x
mov ah, 02
mov dl, x
int 21h
endm

fl macro
int 20h
cseg ends
end start
endm

cls macro
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h
endm

cseg segment para 'code'
assume cs:cseg;ds:cseg;ss:cseg;es:cseg

org 100h
start:jmp begin

fn db ?
sn db ?
n db ?
m db ?

begin:
cls
mov ah,01
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov fn,al
mov ah,01
int 21h

sub al,30h
mov sn,al 
cmp fn,al
ja x1
jmp exit

x1:
mul sn
cmp al,10
jae ilong
pc ' '
add al,30h
add ah,30h
mov n,al
mov m,ah
pc n
pc m
jmp exit 

ilong:mov ah,0
mov al, n
mov bl,10
div bl
add al,30h      ;div ah:al,bl
add ah,30h
mov n,al
mov m,ah
pc ' '
pc n
pc m

exit:fl
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to single step your program. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help. For example, it's unclear why you try to print 2 digits when you have checked that the result is less than 10.

Comment: This is almost a good question.  You described specifically what it did print, which many people fail to do.  But you didn't comment your code so we don't know what exactly you're misunderstanding about how your code works.  And like Jester said, this should be easy to solve if you just single-step in a debugger and watch register values.

Comment: Hint, you can optimize `add al, 30h` / `add ah, 30h` into `add ax, 3030h`.  And you can store with `mov word [n], ax` (because you put `n` and `m` in memory next to each other.)  It's handy that `div` by 10 puts the resulting digits in printing order in AX.

Answer (score 1):

Operating on single digit inputted numbers, the largest result that your program would ever need to print is 64 (8*8). You would get this when the first number is 9 and the second number is 8.

Your program has these 2 problems:

- When the result is indeed smaller than 10 (0,1,4,9) you start by outputting a space character, but then you erroneously try to output **two digits** where you only need to display a single digit!

  ```
    cmp al, 10     ;AX is the product and AH is zero at this point!
    jae ilong
    add al, 30h    ;Turn into text
    mov n, al
    pc  ' '
    pc  n
    jmp exit
  ```
- When it comes to displaying a result larger than 9 (16,25,36,49,64) you immediately start by destroying your calculated square that is in the `AX` register (using `mov ah, 0` `mov al, n`). **Please verify that the *n* variable has no defined value at this point!**

  ```
  ilong:
    mov bl, 10
    div bl
    add ax, 3030h  ;Turn both into text at the same time
    mov n, al
    mov m, ah
    pc  ' '
    pc  n          ;Display tens
    pc  m          ;Display ones
  exit:
    fl
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> if a>b

```
/// ax = a
/// cx = b
/// return result in ax
cmp ax,cx        ; a > b?
ja @SquareB      ; yes, SquareB
ret              ; no, done
```

> , square the value of b

```
@SquareB:        
imul cx,cx       ;b = b * b      
mov ax,cx        ;return b in ax (not sure if you need this step)
ret              ;done
```

When writing assemby you need to write comments for every single line of code.
Detailing exactly **why** you coded it and what you expect to happen.
If you don't you'll be struggling to understand your own code the next day (never mind other people trying to understand your reasoning).

Comment: In x86 16-Bit assembly you can't write "imul cx,cx"; furthermore why not use you NEG/MUL instead of IMUL ? It is more fast at least 7 CPU cycles.

Comment: Excuse me: I mustn't use NEG but the implementation of ABS, instead. But only in the worst case I need of 3 CPU-cycles less. Normally I need 8 CPU-cycles more.

Comment: x86 16-bit is dead, so it's pointless discussing its performance, plus: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly Disassembly:

0:  66 0f af c9             imul   cx,cx, it works just fine.  `imul` takes 3 cycles on the lastest processors last time I checked.

Answer (score -1):

My corrected solution:

```
;  INPUT: AX= A
;         CX= B
; OUTPUT: AX= (A>B) ? Sqr(B) : A

CMP  AX,CX     ; Compare input num. A with input num. B
JLE  @Exit     ; If A<=B, skip the multiplication and exit

MOV  AX,CX     ; Copy input num.B in accumulator AX
; Process ABS(B):
CMP  AX,08000H ; 4 CPU-cycles, if num.B>=0 set carry flag
CMC            ; 2 CPU-cycles, complements carry flag; if B<0 it is set
SBB  CX,CX     ; 3 CPU-cycles, if B<0, CX is set to -1 else is set to 0
XOR  AX,CX     ; 3 CPU-cycles, if B<0, do a 1-complement of num.B
SUB  AX,CX     ; 3 CPU-cycles, if B<0, do a 2-complement of num.B
; IMUL AX needs in the worst case up to 21 CPU-cycles more then MUL
MUL  AX        ; Multiply the absolute value of B for itself

@Exit:

RET            ; Call's return
```

My wrong solution:

```
;  INPUT: AX= A
;         CX= B
; OUTPUT: AX= (A>B) ? Sqr(B) : A

CMP  AX,CX     ; Compare input num. A with input num. B
JLE  @Exit     ; If A<=B, skip the multiplication and exit

MOV  AX,CX     ; Copy input num.B in accumulator AX
NEG  AX        ; I MUSTN'T ALWAYS NEGATE AX, BUT ONLY IF AX<0!
MUL  AX        ; It multiply AX*AX and store the product in DX:AX

@Exit:

RET            ; Call's return
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why are you quoting cycle times for ancient processors? `imul` takes 3 cycles on Skylake. Even on the AMD K7 it took 3 cycles.